# Unable to use :text in typed_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I tried doing

```
  typed_store :meta do |s|
    s.string :name
    s.text   :instructions
  end
```

which gives me an error `key not found: :text` even though `:text` is listed [here](https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore/blob/master/lib/active_record/typed_store/dsl.rb)

`[:string, :text, :integer, :float, :time, :datetime, :date, :boolean, :decimal, :any].each do |type|`

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? `s.string` works but not `s.text`

Comment: Did you add the gem to the Gemfile? Is it spring running?

Comment: Yes, it's in the Gemfile. It's just `s.text` that's giving me `key not found`, `s.string :instructions` works great

Comment: You can inspect the methods available for `s`; `s.methods.grep(/text/)` if isn't there then it's as @morrisetcl said. BTW it seems text is just an alias for string isn't it? What version of the gem are you using?

Comment: My Gemfille.lock says `activerecord-typedstore (1.3.1)`. I don't know how to find out if text is an alias for string...

Comment: Here it seems https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore/blob/2eea562111e5601e00d65cbcc82d2cdc88bda3fb/lib/active_record/typed_store/field.rb#L56, no?

Comment: thank you! I'm still learning to figure these out on my own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the gem allow `text` as permitted type ?

```rb
# lib/active_record/typed_store/field.rb#L38

TYPES = {
      boolean: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean,
      integer: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Integer,
      string: ::ActiveRecord::Type::String,
      float: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Float,
      date: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Date,
      time: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Time,
      datetime: ::ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime,
      decimal: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Decimal,
      any: ::ActiveRecord::Type::Value,
    }

    def lookup_type(type, options)
      TYPES.fetch(type).new(**options)
    end
```

Comment: oh maybe `text` is not allowed. i wonder what  [this](https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore/blob/master/lib/active_record/typed_store/dsl.rb) is for then

```
[:string, :text, :integer, :float, :time, :datetime, :date, :boolean, :decimal, :any].each do |type|
  define_method(type) do |name, **options|
    @fields[name] = Field.new(name, type, options)
  end
end

```